# ASP.NET MVC FormsAuthentication check if user logged in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I want to show some `div` at the view only if user has logged in.

That's how I tried to do it:

```
@{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    // if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <div>
            Some content only for logged in users.
        </div>
    }
}
```

But `Request.IsAuthenticated` (and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`) is **always** `true`, even in the very beginning, right after I start the website from Visual Studio. Apparently, it gets *me* as the user logged in Windows (because `User.Identity.Name` returns my Windows login), but I need it to check if user has authenticated on website via `FormsAuthentication`.

That's my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

How do I check if users has logged in via `FormsAuthentication`?

Comment: For now I did it like that: `if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)`, but that doesn't seem to be the right way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean that you want to check if the user has logged in, I use the following:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { /* content */}
```

Comment: Nope, tried that, it **always** returns `true` as well.

Comment: are you using individual user accounts, organizational, or windows authentication?

Comment: Where? In `web.config` there are only `<authentication mode="Forms">` lines that I mentioned in the post.

Comment: When you first create your application you get to choose the type.

please see the following, this might solve your problem:
http://forums.asp.net/t/2009128.aspx?MVC5+User+Identity+IsAuthenticated+always+returns+true

Comment: Well, I chose `None`, and this selection, when creating new project, only affects `<authentication mode>` in `web.config`.

Comment: Yes, you're were right! The link contains the solution: _In the Properties window, Set Anonymous Authentication to Enabled  and set Windows Authentication to Disabled_.